# Unity MLAPI Instance server

Tags: unity, multiplayer, unity-networking

I am currently developing a multiplayer game with unity using MLAPI sdk.
Right now i have an API Gateway for everything that is not directly gameplay and theirs also Zone servers AKA Gameplay servers. Right now the zone server can handle around 250 players within a single instance of the zone. What i am wondering about is how can i have a dungeons server.
So lets say players in groups of 5 will zone into a dungeon, i cannot have 1 instance of the server running for only 1 group of 5 players. I need to be able to handle multiple groups of 5 entering the dungeons without them seeing each other since they arent in the same group. How would i go about doing this ??

Comment: I have not made such a feature before, but I know a game I played in the past had _layers_. A new "instance" would put you on the same layer as your friends. If you just add an "id" to all the things that happen with the same "group", maybe you could get away with it. So if a server that can handle 250 players, a dungeon server would have 50 _layers_ of 5 players groups.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is how Vaillancourt was saying, which is to only send updates to the players who are in the same group, but not the rest of them.

Another way to do it is to use a service like Edgegap. Basically, you will create a really small instance that's only for a specific number of players and they will deploy it in the best location for all your players. So, instead of having one big server that hosts all the players and runs 24/7, you create small container servers and you only run them for the time that the dungeon lasts. That can help with latency and also save costs in the long run.